# GNOME dock glitches out after unlocking from lock screen on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dock

When I lock the screen with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and log in again (doesn't matter how long the lockscreen is on for) the "original" GNOME dock appears underneath the ubuntu/dashtodock one and causes <kbd>Super</kbd>+[1-9] keys not to work and bugs out some icons of applications that are not added to favorites.

When I reset GNOME by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> "r" this disappears and there is a window saying "Ubuntu bug" stating that there was a problem and in details it says it was a problem with GNOME shell. I already sent the report at least 10 times.